# Report rendering using SSRS in Google Chrome

Tags: reporting-services

Hey, In our project, we use SSRS integrated with asp.net forms to render reports.

The report looks good in IE. when it comes to google chrome, there're some issues we face such as

1. date picker not displayed in the parameter prompt
2. distorted tool bar

Does any one have any idea how to get around this problem in chrome?

I appreciate your inputs. Thanks. Ananth

Comment: My report does not work at all in Chrome.  It works in IE and Firefox.  I am using SSRS 2008 R2.  Are there any settings you had to adjust to see the report in Chrome?  It looks like it ran and the number of pages is correct, it's just that all of the pages are blank.

Brian

Answer (score 1):

To Fix Chrome Date Picker

http://www.rajbandi.net/post/2011/04/03/Fixing-SSRS-Report-Viewer-control-date-picker-in-Google-chrome.aspx

To fix Chrome Distortion

http://www.rajbandi.net/post/2011/04/03/Fixing-ReportViewer-control-toolbar-in-Google-Chrome.aspx

Comment: Here are the correct links: http://rajbandi.net/fixing-ssrs-report-viewer-control-date-picker-in-google-chrome

Comment: Sorry that's dead too!

Answer (score 1):

A non Jquery version of Raj's code to fix the Chrome Distortion is actually quite easy:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .reportViewerCtrl table
    {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is there are several  tags inside the Report Viewer control header.  These table tags have a display type of 'inline', which causes Chrome to generate a newline.

Using the !important tag to overwrite this display type will solve the problem.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of functionality is lost in Chrome, some of the elements can be fixed by Style Sheets. I don't think this will be fixed in future versions of SSRS.
As far as SSRS 2008, quite a few key features are implemented with active-x and it looks like SSRS 2008 R2 will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try forcing the useragent to be firefox. I have just done this to resolve a compatability issue with Chrome.

The user agent I used was

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
```

For more detail see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23603189/3479408